# How to: 'Update values in array using a JavaScript for-loop'

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm creating a webpage on which I want to hide/show certain divs. To do this, I created a for-loop to change the style.display to `none` or `block`. Using the same for-loop I simultaneously want to update an array.

When I hide the div, the array should be empty. But when I show the div it should contain values listed below `[65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55]`.

My issue is; the array updates inside the loop, but not outside. Why is it not updating the array outside the loop?

**The output should be an updated array which can be used outside the for-loop.**

```
var array1 = [];
function hideRightBlock() {
    var x = document.getElementById("text_box_right");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
        var array1 = [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55];
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
        var array1 = [];
    }
}
```

Comment: you're re-initialising array inside condition blocks, just assign value to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are declaring a new variable `array1` inside the `if` and `else` blocks. This variable you declare in there is scoped to the respective block it is declared in.
Instead, modify the `array1` from outside the function:

```
var array1 = [];
function hideRightBlock() {
    var x = document.getElementById("text_box_right");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
        array1 = [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55];
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
        array1 = [];
    }
}
```

**DIFF:** `array1 = [...];` instead of `var array1 = [...];`

**RUNNABLE EXAMPLE**

```js
var array1 = [];

function hideRightBlock() {
    var x = document.getElementById("text_box_right");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
        array1 = [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55];
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
        array1 = [];
    }
    
    //just for displaying array value
    document.getElementById("array-value").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(array1);
}
```

```html
<div id="text_box_right">THIS IS THE BOX</div>
<button type="button" onclick="hideRightBlock()">toggle</button>
<br/>
<br/>
<div id="array-value"></div>
```

Comment: Oh, that makes sense! Though it's still not updating the array...

Comment: I added a runnable example - it seems to work!

Comment: Ah, I had an issue on my end! Thank you so much!

Comment: Let me guess: The id of your text box was not `text_box_right` but `#text_box_right`? :) Glad to help!

Comment: Hahaha knowing me, that could have been the issue. But it actually was a curly bracket that was incorrectly placed. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

It is better initiating variable once `var ...`  . But I think it can't be your problem . Checking element display may be wrong . It is better to check element display by `getComputedStyle` because `style.display` will only know inline style element not external element .....

Check below illustration...

```js
var array1 = [];
function hideRightBlock() {
    var x = document.getElementById("text_box_right");
    var computeStyle = window.getComputedStyle(x);
    if (computeStyle.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
        var array1 = [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55]; // better array1 = [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55];
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
        var array1 = []; //better array1 = [];
    }
    console.log(array1);
}
```

```css
#text_box_right {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="text_box_right" >This is text box right</div>

<button onclick="hideRightBlock()">Show/Hide</button>
```